# How do these extra parameters work with map()?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, functional-programming

I'm working on better understanding functional programming in javascript, but I'm a bit confused by what I've seen fed to map functions. Take the example below:

```js
const f = x => (a, b, c) => b + a;

const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

const m = arr.map(f(1));

document.write(m);
```

When f returns a it will print each value, as expected. If it returns b it seems to return the index, and c will return the entire array for each value. Is there a reason to why this function works this way?

Comment: This function doesn't make any sense. What's the point of the `x` parameter  if it isn't used anywhere? The same effect could be achieved with `arr.map(() => arr)`.

Comment: Yes, the x was left in because I was playing with passing things through and seeing how it affected other elements. In this case I only returned c for simplicities sake.

Comment: Note that this is not currying.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Could you help clarify why it isn't? New to this so it'd help me get my terminology straight. Thought it was since I was passing a function.

Comment: @user3591425 currying (in the context of JavaScript) is where you take a function with arity > 1 and turn it into a series of unary functions. E.g. `const add = (a, b) => a + b;` vs `const curriedAdd = a => b => a + b;`

Comment: For more details about currying, a google search will probably lead you to a detailed article on wikipedia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) callback function has three default parameters

1. The current element of the iteration
2. The index of the current element of the iteration
3. The array that `.map()` function was called upon

`f` returns a function which is set as `callback` of `.map()`

See also [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

Comment: So another way to look at what this function produces is arr.map((a, b, c) => c). a being the element of iteration, b being the index, then c being the array that was called. On the right track?

Comment: @user3591425 Yes

Answer (score 3):

In your example, You are invoking `map` with a 3-ary callback where:
`a` -> current element
`b` -> current index
`c` -> original array

and returning `c`. Therefore, your result will be a new array containing a reference to the original array for every element iterated over.

Since you aren't doing anything with `x`, there is no need for a nested function here. A better example of how you can use this concept would be something like:

```js
const add = a => b => a + b

const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]

const newArr = arr.map(add(3))
// [4, 5, 6, 7]
console.log(newArr)
```

Comment: @Damon can you please add some explanation regarding two time use of `=>` in your example?

Comment: @BlackBeard can you give me a bit more context what you're asking (for example - explain why it can be useful or why I included it here?). OP originally mentioned currying before editing the post, so that was meant to be a trivial example of how you could write a curried function in javascript. In many cases this technique can be used to greatly improve function reusability, but in OP's example it's a no-op.